# Android Fatal Error - Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-permissions, android-savedstate

I'm attempting to perform a fragment transaction after requesting permissions in Android - however the app continually crashes. How might this code be changed in order to avoid this?

Any assistance is appreciated.

**CHECK PERMISSIONS BEFORE SENDING EMAIL:**

```
private void emailShare() {
    if (mayRequestContacts()) {
        emailShareImpl();
    }
}
```

**CHECK PERMISSIONS:**

```
private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        return false;
    }
```

**PERMISSION CHECK RESULT:**

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                emailShareImpl();
            }
        }
    }
```

**INITIATE FRAGMENT TRANSACTION IF PERMISSION GRANTED:**

```
 private void emailShareImpl() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        EmailReferDialog mEmailReferDialog = new EmailReferDialog();
        mEmailReferDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mEmailReferDialog.show(fragmentManager, "EMAIL_REFER_DIALOG");
    }
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
05-11 09:04:58.859 16113-16113/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.example, PID: 16113
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=65536, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example/com.example.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3743)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3786)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:139)
                                                                at com.example.ReferFragment.emailShareImpl(ReferFragment.java:222)
                                                                at com.example.ReferFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(ReferFragment.java:140)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FragmentActivity.java:894)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6582)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6460)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3739)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3786) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happens because `onRequestPermissionresult` is called before activity's `onResume`. You can simply fix this by following:

```
private boolean mShareEmail = false;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mShareEmail = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mShareEmail) {
        emailShareImpl();
        mShareEmail = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was moving to another fragment. I had this same problem. you have to put code in onResume

Comment: @Artem Mostyaev Thanks a lot

Comment: @Artem Mostyaev "onRequestPermissionresult is called before activity's onResume" is that always true? Or is something random?

Comment: It is always true from my experience. But I can't find any official proof..

Comment: I faced this issue on android 6.0 but 8.0 and above the same code is working fine without ever crashing. Seems like google fixed it in future releases.

Comment: Maybe.. Anyway, the code is needed for backward compatibility. Android 7 is still very popular.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following tip is a bit late, but instead of a workaround, if you don't use the activity's state (for example, the permission model should be stateless), you should use **commitAllowingStateLoss** during fragment transition.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this proble by Add a handler :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FolderChooserDialog.Builder(ReportActivity.this)
                        .tag(REQUEST_CODE_Excel+"")
                        .show();
            }
        }, 500);
```